# Clearing app storage

Tags: android, memory-management, sharedpreferences, storage

My app uses banner ads and unfortunately, every time a banner is loaded / displayed, the app's 'storage' jumps up by some amount.  To get an idea of how much, the app uses around 21.69MB when first installed. Within a day, this can reach 30MB.  The most it's got up to is 51MB. At that point I cleared the storage.

Now, if I disable ads, then the problem vanishes.  I've contacted my ad network who advised upgrading my SDK which I did, but it's made no difference.

The thing is, this seems to be a fairly common occurrence, I've downloaded 2 or 3 games from the Play Store and tested, by launching, exiting and relaunching the apps over and over and indeed, the storage increases.

My 2 questions are:

- Is there any way (programmatically) to clear an app's storage (say from within onDestroy)
- If there is, is there any way to do this while retaining the shreadPrefs which I use for things like users settings, levels unlocked etc.

Comment: When you ran your app in an emulator, and you looked in internal storage to see where the ad network software was putting its files, what did you learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! The ads banners are probably stored on the **app cache**.

You can get the app cache path with the method `Context.getCacheDir()` (as mentionned [on the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29))!

So, I suggest you to **clear the entire app cache directory** to do as you want. Fortunately, the preferences are stored in the app data directory!

Comment: Hey @KevinVuilleumier, thanks for this, unforuntalely, I don't think it's stored in the cache folder.  I've tried clearing it and it makes no difference :-(  Also, when I look at the app settings, the 'Clear cache' button is disabled (indicating it's empty) - the app's 'Clear Data' button is active though so it must be somewhere  else.  I'll see if I can find out where it's putting the files.

Comment: @Zippy Have you tried to browse the app data directory? Have you permission to write to the external storage?

Comment: No, but your answer, on further research, let me to this http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically, I managed to find out from some experimentation from this that clearing the app_webview folder seems to do the trick, however, I've read that app SDK is just caching ads for quicker loading, and the Android OS should clear the cache if it gets too big anyway.  So, I may just leave it if this is how it's intended to be.  But will mark your answer as it led me to this! (Now sure how true this is though about the OS clearing the cache itself).

Comment: I'm glad to help you! And yes, I doubt that the OS clear the cache by itself.